# How can I use conditional constant in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I want to use conditional constant

If I get a index 1, then return A, if I get a index 2, then return B, if I get a index 3, then return C

for example... like this.

```
  const element = (data, index) => (
switch(index){

case '1' :
        <View>
          <Text> A </Text>
        </View>
        break;

case '2' :
        <View>
          <Text> B</Text>
        </View>
        break;

case '3' :
        <View>
          <Text> C</Text>
        </View>
        break;
}
)
```

How can I make that..
thanks for your help

Comment: react suggest to use jsx statement inside render function , { condition && <view/> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get switch statement out of the render function and just call it by passing necessary value

```
switchFunc = (val) => {
   case val :
        return(<View>
          <Text> A </Text>
        </View>)
        break;

  case val :
        return(<View>
          <Text> B</Text>
        </View>)
        break;

  case val :
        return(<View>
          <Text> C</Text>
        </View>)
        break;
 }
}

render() {
  return (
      <>
      {this.switchFunc(param)} 
      </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in your jsx file

```
const getElement = (data, index) => (
switch(index){

  case '1' :
        return(<View>
          <Text> A </Text>
        </View>)
        break;

  case '2' :
        return(<View>
          <Text> B</Text>
        </View>)
        break;

  case '3' :
        return(<View>
          <Text> C</Text>
        </View>)
        break;
 }
)
```

And in your main component

```
<Component>{getElement(data,index)}</Component>
```